# Unable to set arguments to convert image files to video

Tags: macos, command-line, ffmpeg, command-line-arguments, macos-highsierra

I've a bunch of files in a folder with the following format:

`center_2016_12_01_13_%2d_%2d_%3d.jpg`

I'm trying to use FFmpeg to convert into a video with this command:

`ffmpeg -n -i "center_2016_12_01_13_%2d_%2d_%3d.jpg" output.m4v`

But I keep getting this error:

> ```
> center_2016_12_01_13_%2d_%2d_%3d.jpg: No such file or directory
> ```

Here's an example of an image that I have:
`center_2016_12_01_13_41_15_788.jpg`

What is missing here? I checked that I run this command inside the folder.

Comment: The images need to be consecutively numbered. Use the concat demuxer instead. See superuser.com/a/1379084

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your input file mask

```
center_2016_12_01_13_%2d_%2d_%3d.jpg
```

is that it use *multiple* placeholders — `%2d` `%2d` `%3d`.

You have to rename your files in such a way that you can use *only one placeholder.*

---

My tip how to reach it:

Use *Total Commander Multi-Rename Tool* (see [How to Rename Many Files at Once With Total Commander](https://www.howtogeek.com/56580/how-to-rename-many-files-at-once-with-total-commander/)):

- copy your files into a new directory (for safety)
- sort them by name (to keep their order)
- select them all (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)
- launch Multi-Rename Tool (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>)
- in the Multi-Rename Tool window: see the picture:
- [image]